# Как проверить конструктор оператором noexcept

Tags: c++, c++17

Есть, к примеру, такая функция:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(const T & stuff) noexcept(noexcept(bar(stuff)))
{
    return bar(stuff);
}
```

Вопрос, как проверить в `noexcept` копирующий/перемещающий конструктор того что вернет `bar(stuff)`?

Answer (score 1):

В С++17 в этом коде копирующий или перемещающий конструктор для объекта, возвращаемого `bar`, вызываться не будет. Новые правила предписывают максимальное откладывание непосредственного создания объекта с исключением промежуточных копий. Например этот код будет рабочим, даже несмотря на запрет копирующих / перемещающих конструкторов:

```
class A;

A bar(int const x);

class A
{
    friend A bar(int const x);
    private: A(void) = delete;
    private: A(A const & other) = delete;
    private: A(A && other) = delete;
    private: explicit A(int const x) : m_x{x} {}
    private: A & operator =(A const & other) = delete;
    private: A & operator =(A && other) = delete;
    private: [[maybe_unused]] int m_x;
};

A bar(int const x) { return A{x}; }

template<typename T>
auto foo(T const & stuff) noexcept(noexcept(bar(stuff)))
{
    return bar(stuff);
}

int main() 
{
    [[maybe_unused]] A a{foo(1)};
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qOfEKXv9g7g7aUNC)

Comment: Таки что делать?

Comment: @Cerbo Ничего, текущей проверки достаточно.

Comment: А зачем `private:` в каждой строке? И в чем смысл двойного `private: private:`?

Comment: @freim Чтобы обозначить видимость каждого символа отдельно, как это делается в нормальных языках. То была опечатка.

Comment: Всё жжоте стилем :-D А в чём смысл `maybe_unused` у члена-данных класса, он же инициализируется? Может надо `::std::optional` добавить? Ну и `A(void)` это как-то сишечно совсем.

Comment: @älёxölüt Без `maybe_unused` clang будет ругаться на инициализированное, но не использованное поле `m_x`. Что  касается `A(void)`, то можно было использовать специальное обозначение для пустого перечня аргументов, но так как для этих целей ничего стандартного нету, то я решил сократить.

Comment: Так убрать этот `m_x` тогда вовсе и далее по цепочке. Минимальный код в ответе это же из той же оперы, что и [mcve] в вопросе. А пустые скобки `()` вместо `(void)` чем не угодили не пойму.

Comment: @älёxölüt Ну вот без поля в классе это был бы не полный пример, а так видно, что данные все-таки передаются правильно.

Comment: @VTT Насколько я помню, там речь идет о вложенных *промежуточных* вызовах, в конце стека куда-то объект должен скопироваться и там нужен оператор или конструктор.

Comment: @VTT Во-вторых вы привели частный случай, но вывод делаете общий. То есть, если класс будет обычный с полным набором конструкторов и операторов, то по вашему они не будет вызываться.

Comment: @Cerbo Это делаю не я, это сделано в стандарте. Копирующие / перемещающие конструкторы не будут вызываться даже при их наличии. И даже если они имеют побочные эффекты. Так что останется только вызов конструктора `A(int const x)`, причем место под объект и его область видимости будут в `main`, в то время как конструктор вызовется внутри `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Почему так нельзя?

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(const T& stuff) noexcept(noexcept(decltype(bar(stuff)){decltype(bar(stuff)){}})) {
    return bar(stuff);
}
```

Для перемещающего ещё declval накинуть.

Comment: А почему внутри еще один `decltype`?

Comment: @VTT для создания объекта конструктором по умолчанию

Comment: По-моему это аналогично `noexcept(noexcept(decltype(bar(stuff)){bar(stuff)}))`… однако конечный результат может быть неверным, например когда `bar` объявлен как `noexcept` а конструктор копирования - нет

Comment: @VTT по-моему - нет. В моём примере нужен конструктор по умолчанию, а в вашем - нет. В моём вызов конструктора будет смодедирован всегда, а в вашем действительно может возникнуть такая ситуция. Но я не уверен

Comment: Так дело в том, что для `return bar(stuff);` конструктор по-умолчанию не нужен, а копирующий / перемещающий вызваны не будут.